# How to write script that saves the processid of a daemon process?

Tags: linux, bash, process, daemon

I am working with a client-server program. My server program is a daemon process. I need to write scripts that start and stop the daemon. For this, I need to find a way to store the daemon's processid . I've heard bash scripting might be a good solution. I want to store the processID of the daemon in a file called revd.pid under /var/run.

My program looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

pid = $!

echo pid >> /var/run/revd.pid
```

Comment: The `$!` variable in bash represents the last process running in the background. Just `echo` it and redirect to a file to save the PID.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have edited my question and put my program there. Would really like your feedback.

Comment: What language is your daemon written in and how is it first started? (Manually, at system boot, etc.)?

Comment: My daemon is written in C and starts when i compile the server

Comment: You might try calling [getpid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) and write the value to a file. By convention, the PIDs are stored as ASCII numbers followed by a newline ("31415\n") in files like `/var/run/foo.pid`.

Comment: I could write bash script in C too, right? Feels easier than emacs, vi or any other editor.

Comment: Good advice, I have now taken the last command by $! and but it into a file.

Comment: Now that I've stored the process ID of the daemon (hopefully correctly), my task is to make one script to start it and one to stop it. Got any advice on that?

Comment: Getting error: lastprocess: command doesn't exist

Comment: solved, by changing places on lastprocess and echo

Comment: The file seems empty though so not sure if my code is working. When i go to /home/me (file location) and try to run file.txt (chmod +x file.txt) i get no output.

Comment: Seems like it needs to be placed under  /var/run/. I am trying "echo $! >> /var/run/revd.pid" but it doesn't work. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command `pidof <application_name>` 
Here  is your daemon process.

Below is an example of the above in a shell script.

Create empty file `revd.pid` under `/var/run` and give it proper permissions ...so that you can write into it.

```
pid=`pidof chrome`
echo "$pid" >> /var/run/revd.pid
```

Comment: Thank you! But it seems like it needs to be placed under  /var/run/. How do I do this? I am trying this:

"echo $! >> /var/run/revd.pid"

Comment: echo $! prints the PID of the last background process.  it does not help for your situation.

Comment: Ill give your program a try :)

Comment: Can you elaborate can't open file for writing" ..what are doing ..Can you give me more details.

Comment: Have a look at the permissions ...the file might not be having write permission.

Comment: Solved the "can't open file for writing" by being superuser. But the file revd.pid isn't created, I want it under /var/run with the processID of the daemon. I'm doing:

#!/bin/bash

pidof = 'redv.pid' //program name

pid = 'pidof redv.pid'

echo "$pid" >> /var/run/revd.pid

Comment: Yeah thanks for helping out with superuser, but the program still isnt working :(

Comment: I am trying to store the processID of the daemonprocess in a file by creating  the file named revd.pid under /var/run and echo the processID of the daemon to the file. I'm using the code i mentioned above, but the file never gets created.

Comment: Hmm..at this point ..I need to look at the files ..to get a Gist ..is it possible ?

Comment: What files do you want to see? I can print the files you need to see

Comment: Send me what you have ..as I will not be having any idea of whats going on over there.

Comment: Alright. This screenshot shows all I got https://gyazo.com/ec106e93e728f0d51754b27339dda25d

As you can see, the file revd.pid isn't created. It is supposed to be created, and contain the daemon process ID and it should be under /var/run

Comment: 3rd line is doing a 'pidof redvpid'. That's wrong ... as it is a file not the daemon process. Use the appropriate daemon process.